# C#-Regular expression for email, but exclude "hotmail,gmail,yahoo"

Tags: c#, regex

How can I rewrite this regular expression in order to match all email addresses, but not those
which contains "**hotmail,gmail and yahoo**". So far I wrote this:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@(?<!hotmail|gmail|yahoo)((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

Comment: More localized version: _"C#-Regular expression for email, but exclude “John@gmail.com”"_

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to validate e-mail addresses!** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: Ok. I will do it in c#.Thank you for recommendation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the negative lookbehind to a negative lookahead by removing the `<`, and reposition it as follows

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(?!hotmail|gmail|yahoo)(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

The above assumes that `"hotmail,gmail and yahoo"` would directly follow the `@`.

Shorter equivalent:

```
@"^([\w.-]+)@(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}|(?!hotmail|gmail|yahoo)(([a-zA-Z\d-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|\d{1,3})(\]?)$"
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your solution but this email does not match the RegEx : aa@gmaill.com. It should match because it's "gmaill" and not "gmail"